# How to show Document ID in an excel file cell?

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010

In sharepoint 2010 I have a document library. When you create a new document in this library, this document gets automatic a document ID. I would like to show this document ID in a cel in an excel file. These document ID is available as a property in a excel file.

I have try the macros below, but they didnt work for the document id property. Other properties are working fine . Is there another solution?

[image]

I have tried these macros scripts:

```
Public Function GetMyCustomDocumentProperties(prop As String) As String
    GetMyCustomDocumentProperties = ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties(prop)
End Function

Public Function GetMyBuiltinDocumentProperties(prop As String) As String
    GetMyBuiltinDocumentProperties = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(prop)
End Function
```

Error I got in the cell:

```
#VALUE!
```

This is the value of cel A4:

=GetMyCustomDocumentProperties("Document ID Value")

This is the value of cel A5:

=GetMyBuiltinDocumentProperties("Document ID Value")

Comment: Where is `GetMyProp` defined and what `prop` are you supplying? And you should also confirm what errors you receive (if any).

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the code. It was a typo. But the problem is still available. See my post above for the error I got.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was:

```
Public Function GetMyContentTypeProperties(prop As String) As String
    GetMyContentTypeProperties = ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties(prop)
End Function
```